# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.huawei.hiai.common.AIRuntimeException" on path

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence

I tried to create an application using [HiAI](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/devservice/doc/20201302) to try out the Image Super-Resolution.

The activity's code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_isr);

    Thread thread = new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                            1001);
                }
            }
    );
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        // Let's read picked image data - its URI
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));


        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        // Do something with the bitmap

        bitmap = ShrinkBitmap(imagePath, 700, 500);

        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        // At the end remember to close the cursor or you will end with the RuntimeException!
        cursor.close();
    }
}

public void press(View v) {
    Log.i("AI", "Feladat előtt");

    VisionBase.init(this, new ConnectionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnect() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnect() {
        }
    });

    /** Define class detector，the context of this project is the input parameter */
    ImageSuperResolution superResolution = new ImageSuperResolution(this);
    /** Define the frame, put the bitmap that needs to detect the image into the frame*/
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    /** BitmapFactory.decodeFile input resource file path*/
    //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(null); //TODO
    frame.setBitmap(bitmap);
    /** Define and set super-resolution parameters*/
    SuperResolutionConfiguration paras = new SuperResolutionConfiguration(
            SuperResolutionConfiguration.SISR_SCALE_3X,
            SuperResolutionConfiguration.SISR_QUALITY_HIGH);
    superResolution.setSuperResolutionConfiguration(paras);
    /** Run super-resolution and get result of processing */
    ImageResult result = superResolution.doSuperResolution(frame, null);
    /** After the results are processed to get bitmap*/
    Bitmap bmp = result.getBitmap();
    /** Note: The result and the Bitmap in the result must be NULL, but also to determine whether the returned error code is 0 (0 means no error)*/


    /** Source release */
    VisionBase.destroy();
    Log.i("AI", "Destroy után");

    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    Log.i("AI", "Kirajzolva");
}

Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height) {

    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

    int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight / (float) height);
    int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth / (float) width);

    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1) {
        if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
        } else {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
        }
    }

    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
    return bitmap;
}
```

It starts the gallery app, to select a picture, crop the picture to a good resolution and a button to start the AI feature to work. It should display the picture in an imageview.
However, when I run the application on my phone, after I press the button to let the AI do it's thing, these 4 following errors come up:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

...

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)

...

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/huawei/hiai/common/AIRuntimeException;

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.huawei.hiai.common.AIRuntimeException" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/hu.hiai.aitestapp -8V0mgETpAnjXZ5HAotNGPA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/hu.hiai.aitestapp-8V0mgETpAnjXZ5HAotNGPA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
```

There are 3 files in the app/libs folder:

- vision-oversea-release.aar  - this got added automatically by DevEco
- huawei-hiai-vision.aar  - This was in the zip from huawei's site
- Huawei_IDE.jar  - This was in an another zip from the website, and added as a last test, but it didn't solved anything.

The build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "hu.hiai.aitestapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation(name: 'vision-oversea-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':vision-oversea-release')
    implementation project(':huawei-hiai-vision')
    implementation files('libs/Huawei_IDE.jar')
}

repositories {
     flatDir {
          dirs 'libs'
     }
}
```

I would appreciate it really if anybody could help with this!

Answer (score 0):

My colleague has similar problem, it happens when his code calls FaceCompare method. As it happens there's no such class in the HiAI library. So what do we do?

It looks like it's thrown if the FaceCompare method called in UI thread, so we move it to another thread and we don't meet that exception anymore.